# Update statement in my project not updating data in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to update the record of Employee.MY query shows the message "Employee record updated Successfully"  but it is not updating in table My code goes like this

```
{
$eid=intval($_GET['uin']);
$uin=$_POST['uin'];
$fname=$_POST['firstName'];
$lname=$_POST['lastName'];   
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$department=$_POST['department']; 
$recoffr=$_POST['recoffr']; 
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$sql="
update tblemployees 
   set FirstName = :fname
     , LastName = :lname
     , email = :email
     , department = :department
     , recoffr = :recoffr
     , Phonenumber = :mobileno 
 where uin = :eid
";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':uin',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':fname',$fname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':lname',$lname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':department',$department,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':recoffr',$recoffr,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':mobileno',$mobileno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$msg="Employee record updated Successfully";

}
```

My table structure is [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJp7R.jpg)

Comment: Look (and show) final SQL text received by MySQL in General Log. Is it correct? Does its execution via CLI updates the row(s)?

Comment: @Akina I am new to SQL Kindly explain plz

Comment: @Akina I did that still not working

Comment: @Akina I changed like this   $query->bindParam(':eid',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @Akina I dont think that INTEGER will have any problem .Any way kindly suggest me what to change in code .

Comment: because While Inserting the data in table it is PARAM_STR

Comment: Enable General log temporarily `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`, execute your query, disable log back, then open its file, find actual SQL code received by MySQL and show it. Details: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html).

Comment: Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after you create your connection oject. PDO will then throw exceptions at you when it encounters any issues. Mandatory when troubleshooting database interactions.

Comment: @Akina  could not get any thing by log

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned Uin to wrong Id

```
$query->bindParam(':eid',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

not

```
$query->bindParam(':uin',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: @Akina I am talking about wrong use of parameter name

Comment: @noone Please echo the query generated and add in the question

Comment: update tblemployees set FirstName=:fname,LastName=:lname,email=:email,department=:department,recoffr=:recoffr,Phonenumber=:mobileno where uin=:eid
)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
 if (isset($_GET['uin'])) {
            $ID = $_GET['uin'];
        } else {
            $ID = "";
        }
    $tblemployees_data = array();
    
        $sql_query = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, department, recoffr, mobileno
                        FROM tblemployees
                        WHERE uin = ?";
    
    if ($query_category->prepare($sql_query)) {
            // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
            $query_category->bind_param('s', $ID);
            // Execute query
            $query_category->execute();
            // store result
            $query_category->store_result();
            $query_category->bind_result($previous_category_image);
            $query_category->fetch();
            $query_category->close();
        }
```